# how to use future_lapply and data.table to read huge folder of csvs in a loop and return summary table

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, bigdata

I have a folder of 10,000+ csv files stored on my hard drive. Each csv is for a species and gives presence in raster cells (so over 5million cells if the species were present in every cell on earth).

I need to read each file and use dplyr to join to other data frames and summarise, then return a summary df. I don't have a server to run this on and it's stalling my desktop. It works with a subset of 17 species csvs, but even then it's slow.

This is similar to a few other questions about dealing with big data, but I can't figure out the right combination of packages like data.table, bigmemory, and future. I think the really slow part is the dplyr commands, as opposed to reading the files, but I'm not sure.

I'm not sure if this is possible to answer without the files, but they're huge so not sure how to make this reproducible?

```
spp_ids <- <vector of the species ids, in this case 17 of them>

spp_list <- <datafame with ids of the 17 spp in the folder>

spp_info <- <dataframe with the species id and then some other columns>

cellid_df <- <big df with 5 million+ cell ids and corresponding region names>

# Loop
spp_regions <- future_lapply(spp_ids, FUN = function(x) {

csv_file <- file.path("//filepathtoharddrivefolder", 
sprintf('chrstoremove_%s.csv', x)) # I pull just the id number from the file names

# summarise number of regions and cells
spp_region_summary <- data.table::fread(csv_file, sep = ",") %>%
dplyr::mutate(spp_id = x) %>%
dplyr::filter(presence == 1) %>% # select cell ids where the species is present
dplyr::left_join(cellid_df, by = "cell_id") %>% 
dplyr::group_by(region, spp_id) %>%
dplyr::summarise(num_cells = length(presence)) %>%
dplyr::ungroup()

# add some additional information
spp_region_summary <- spp_region_summary %>%
dplyr::left_join(spp_info, by = "spp_id") %>%
dplyr::left_join(spp_list, by = "spp_id") %>%
dplyr::select(region, spp_id, num_cells)

return(spp_region_summary)
})

spp_regions_df <- dplyr::bind_rows(spp_regions)

fwrite(spp_regions_df,"filepath.csv")
```

Haven't worked with this much data before so I've never had to leave the tidyverse!

Comment: Can you provide a few sample tables and show us what the output should look like?

Comment: Also, in the last block, you're performing 2 joins and then selecting only `region, spp_id, num_cells` which were in the original `spp_region_summary`. It doesn't seem to serve any purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried to reproduce this. I generated 10 million rows for `cellid_df` and each individual file. It only took about 40 seconds for 15 "files" (Using reprex added an extra 20 seconds).

If you can leave your laptop running for half a day or so, this should do it.

A couple of suggestions:

1. You can write to file if you're worried about memory issues.
2. Since `spp_id` is unique in each iteration, you can add it in after the merge. It will save some time.
3. The "additional information" can be joined to the final dataframe since it is keyed on `spp_id`. In `data.table`, `left_join(X,Y,by='id')` will become `Y[X,on='id']`

```r
library(data.table)

spp_ids <- 1:15
set.seed(123)
N <- 1e7 # number of cell_ids

# Dummy cell ids + regions
cellid_df <- data.table(cell_id=1:N,region=sample(state.abb,N,replace = T))
head(cellid_df)
#>    cell_id region
#> 1:       1     NM
#> 2:       2     IA
#> 3:       3     IN
#> 4:       4     AZ
#> 5:       5     TN
#> 6:       6     WY
# 

outfile <- 'test.csv' 
if(file.exists(outfile))
  file.remove(outfile)

a=Sys.time()
l<- lapply(spp_ids, function(x){
  #Generate random file with cell_id and presence
  spp_file <- data.table(cell_id=1:N,presence=round(runif(N))) 

  present_cells <- cellid_df[spp_file[presence==1],on='cell_id'] # Filter and merge
  spp_region_summary <- present_cells[,.(spp_id=x,num_cells=.N),by=.(region)] # Summarise and add
  setcolorder(spp_region_summary,c('spp_id','region','num_cells')) # Reorder the columns if you want

  fwrite(spp_region_summary,outfile,append = file.exists(outfile)) # Write the summary to disk to avoid memory issues
  # If you want to keep it in memory, you can return it and use rbindlist
  # spp_region_summary
})
b=Sys.time()
b-a
#> Time difference of 1.019157 mins
# Check lines in file = (No of species) x (No of regions) + 1
R.utils::countLines(outfile) 
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'R.oo':
#>   method        from       
#>   throw.default R.methodsS3
#> [1] 751
#> attr(,"lastLineHasNewline")
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2019-12-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I think this is really close, and I see where you made this way faster than my messy half-dplyr code. I replaced your spp_file <- line by reading the csvs first outside the loop, but I still get an error on the merge and filter step (Error.. unused argument (on = "cell_id"). Can't figure out why it doesn't recognize the cell_id col

Comment: `spp_file <- list.files(path = "pathtofolder", 
                    pattern = "*.csv", full.names = TRUE) %>%
  map_df(~read_csv(., col_types = cols(.default = "c")))`  so the loop is exactly what you did except without the spp_file line

Comment: Can you show a sample of what these files look like? Also, if you're binding the files outside the loop, you need a column for the `spp_id` if it isn't part of the original file already

Comment: The files are named with the species id, then have 2 cols, c("cell_id","presence"). I used a combo of your answer and my original code and it worked, but took 9 hours on my desktop (64bit, 16 GB ram so not a small machine). I think your idea to use the outfile to write the summary to disk and remove some repetitive steps I had, helped to speed it up a lot